# can't animate an appended image

Tags: jquery

I use `javascript` code to creat a new image element and set it's `src` attribute then append it to an 'a' tag. Then I use `setInterval()` to call `slide()` function which is supposed to move the image to the left then makes it fades out, however the image fades out but it doesn't move at all.

```
function slide(){

var img=$("img");


img.animate({"left": '150'}, "slow", function() {

img.fadeOut("slow", function() {

forward();

img.fadeTo("slow",1);

          }); 

          });

               }

setInterval(function(){slide();}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should position the image absolutely for it to be able to move.
Add this css to your page
`img{
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
}`

*note that all images will be positioned absolutely if you use a selector like `img` in your css*

Here's a fiddle with it in action - http://jsfiddle.net/friiks/qXvy7/

Comment: well thanks, now there's another problem after the img moves and fades it's removed and a new one is appended, i want it to be appended at the original position and so on, i tried using "img.css("left","0");" to reset the position but it doesn't work

Comment: What happens? Is the new image positioned where the previous one was removed? 
Also, please post the code you're using